# Passive voice Usage

Tags: grammar

`You are currently shown` as the Identity Sponsor for at least one contractor who has an Assignment End date, or an Attestation Date that falls in the next three days. Total Six contractors are approaching the attestation end date. `Action must be taken` if these contractors need continued access to ABC IT.

What am I doing wrong here?. I am told that I am incorrectly using passive voice here?.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, except that the last sentence could be rewritten in the active voice - but proofreading is off-topic.

Comment: "I am told" - who is telling you this?  If it is a grammar-checking program, ignore it.  Grammar-checking programs hate the passive voice, for some reason.